# Which observations are associated to the topic model in LDA with sklearn package implementation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, lda, unsupervised-learning, sklearn-pandas

I have successfully implemented this [example in Sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html) and I can see the topics just fine,but how do I revert to the observations that those topics were formed on? I know that this is possible using SAS enterprise miner but I don't know how to do this in sklearn. 
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [transform](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html#sklearn.lda.LDA.transform) method in LDA and [NMF](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html#sklearn.decomposition.NMF.transform) helped give the probabilities of the observation belonging to the topics.

Answer (score 1):

The **NMF** (Non-Negative Matrix Factorization) decomposes a positive matrix into the product of two positive matrices as shown below.

[image]

In your case, `V` is the TF-IDF matrix obtained from your text corpus. The NMF decomposes it into `W` which is called the **topic** matrix as each column represent a topic (each row is a representative word of the topic) ans `H` which is called the **activation** matrix (*weights*).

Therefore, each of your text corpus is a linear combination of your topics. So you cannot really speak of topic membership - which text belongs to which topic - since it can belong to all of them with certain degrees.

Comment: I was able to figure out which observations had a liklihood of which topic. Used the [transform](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html#sklearn.lda.LDA.transform) method in LDA and [NMF](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html#sklearn.decomposition.NMF.transform). Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

The method `fetch_20newsgroups` does exactly that when you load the data before processing it.

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups.html#sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups) is a link to the documentation of the function if you want to see how it works.

**Basically**, when you work with `sklearn` **datasets** you import the module `datasets` and you call some functions that go and fecth the data from your local dataset directory.

Here is where you can find the data :

[image: /sklearn/datasets/]

It contains a `data` directory with some csv files :

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if we are speaking of the same issue. For example I have 30 Topics, I want to be able to see which observations correspond to topic 2 and which observations correspond to topic 15, etc. The 20newsgroup function just grabs the dataset so that you can do whatever you want with it.